# Jersey: How do I catch JSON mapping/parsing errors on user request?

Tags: java, json, exception, jersey

Example endpoint:

```
@POST
@Path("/user")
@Consumes("application/json")
private Response saveUser(User user) {
//do something return Response.class
}
```

From my understanding, Jersey converts the JSON from the post body to the User object.

Assuming that the client POSTS a JSON that is NOT well formatted (invalid JSON, not user object, etc), how do I catch the error that was thrown by Jersey?

The ExceptionMapper that I have doesn't catch it. But if I set `String json` as a parameter and then map it to a `User` object using `ObjectMapper`, it catches it.

If possible, I would love it if I could not use `ClientResponseFilters` and `ContainerResponseFilters` for the reason that I would like all my exception/error handling on just one place, which is an ExceptionMapper.

Plus, `ExceptionMapper` seems to be the appropriate class to handle `Exceptions`.

This is the error that I get:

`Unexpected character ('a' (code 97)): was expecting double-quote to start field name at [Source: org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$UnCloseableInputStream@6d4a3a6f; line: 3, column: 28]`

**EDIT: For those of you not reading the body of my post and just marking it as duplicate: I do have an ExceptionMapper registered but the error goes past it.**

Comment: My question is similar but I need a different solution. Not a duplicate. @peeskillet. Hope you can provide a solution for this one because the one you linked doesnt work

Comment: Are you not using Jackson as the JSON provider? If you aren't, I'll reopen the question. Otherwise, the answer in the duplicate is the solution. If you can't get it to work, please post enough information to reproduce the error. The key is _enough information_.

Comment: _"I do have an ExceptionMapper registered but the error goes past it"_ - because Jackson has its own ExceptionMappers that are more specific... which is also explained int the duplicate